# Potentially a XSS jQuery attack on .NET website

Tags: asp.net, xss

Browsing through the logs of my `ASP.NET` website I saw that line:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&). at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)

The path is:

```
http://example.com/scripts/&&!bs.test(a)&&(p.support.htmlserialize||!bu.test(a))&&(p.support.leadingwhitespace||!bn.test(a))&&!bz[(bp.exec(a)||[
```

Is it some kind of a inner script bug, or someone is trying to find vulnerabilities on my website?

Comment: having googled 'p.support.htmlserialize' test/hack the results would suggest someone was trying to test vulnerabilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an unusual error message in your logs someone was attempting an XSS attack. Luckily the MVC Framework blocks these requests by default.